# Disable use of places.sqlite in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I notice that in recent versions of Firefox, the level of disk access has greatly increased and it is mostly involving two files: "places.sqlite" and "places.sqlite_shm". These files are apparently a SQLite database where Firefox is story "history" information. Firefox is accessing these files dozens of times a second, even when I am not using the browser at all.

I don't really care about history information. Is there any way to totally disable the use of these files?

Comment: What OS? History is useful (helps when entering URL, or reopen  recently closed tab...).   I have a 70MB `places.sqlite` and don't notice any undue disk activity (FF54 on Linux). The disk I/O counters for the process show 400MB written and 5MB read. I suspect the 400MB are mostly the page cache.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GNU/Linux then I would do sth like:

`rm ~/.mozilla/firefox/XXXXXXXX.default/places.sqlite
touch ~/.mozilla/firefox/XXXXXXXX.default/places.sqlite
chattr +i ~/.mozilla/firefox/XXXXXXXX.default/places.sqlite`